# Is $v v^T \succeq 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-semidefinite

Suppose $v \in \mathbb{R}^m$ is an $m$-dimensional vector. Then is it true that $v v^T$ is positive semi-definite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is true.  To verify that this is the case, note that for any complex vector $x$:
$$
x^*(vv^*)x = (x^* v)(v^* x) = |\langle x,v \rangle|^2 \geq 0
$$
Or, restrict $x$ to real vectors and note that $vv^T$ is symmetric.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clear answer. Is there also a simple way to prove in this case $A v v^T$ is positive semi-definite if $A$ is positive semi-definite any symmetric?

Comment: There isn't because this isn't true.  For example, take
$$
A = \pmatrix{2&0\\0&1}, \quad v = \pmatrix{1\\1}
$$
the product of two PSD matrices will always, however, have non-negative eigenvalues.

Comment: Oh. Yes. You are absolutely right. I, fortunately, only need the positivity of the eigenvalues. Could you please give me a reference on the proof that product of two PSD matrices has always positive eigenvalues?

Comment: See Horn and Johnson (new edition), corollary 7.6.2 page 486. There is an easy proof in the case that $A$ is non-singular, which can be used to give an alternate proof (to that given in the reference) in the general case.

Comment: You may want to ask for a proof to this theorem in a new question-post.

Comment: In my case $A$ is non-singular (I posted a new question as you suggested http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/982797/prove-that-the-product-of-two-positive-semidefinite-and-symmetric-matrices-has-n). Thanks a lot for your helps :-)

Answer (score 3):

Yes; it's true since

$$\left\langle vv^Tx,x\right\rangle=\left\langle v^Tx,v^Tx\right\rangle=\left|\left|v^T x\right|\right|^2\ge0 .$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $z$ be a vector. Then $z^Tvv^T z = (zv^T)^T(zv^T) = \langle z, v \rangle^2$. This is just a square of a real number. What do you know about squares of real numbers?

Answer (score 0):

If $\mathrm v \in \mathbb R^n \setminus \{0_n\}$, then $\mathrm v \mathrm v^T$ is a symmetric, rank-$1$ matrix with a single **nonzero eigenvalue**

$$\lambda = \mbox{tr} (\mathrm v \mathrm v^T) = \mbox{tr} (\mathrm v^T \mathrm v) = \|\mathrm v\|_2^2 > 0$$

Thus, $\mathrm v \mathrm v^T$ is **positive semidefinite**.