# The product of two symmetric, positive semidefinite matrices has non-negative eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-semidefinite

How can I prove the following?

> If $A$ and $B$ are two symmetric, positive semidefinite matrices then all eigenvalues of $AB$ are non-negative.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/113842/339790

Answer (score 7):

Suppose that $A$ is non-singular.  Then $AB$ is similar to 
$$
A^{-1/2} (AB) A^{1/2} = (A^{1/2}) B(A^{1/2})
$$
Letting $C = A^{1/2}$, we have $(A^{1/2}) B(A^{1/2}) = C^*BC$, which means that $(A^{1/2}) B(A^{1/2})$ is congruent to $B$, and is thus symmetric and positive semidefinite. Since $AB$ is similar to a positive semidefinite matrix, its eigenvalues are non-negative.

Otherwise, we note that for $t>0$, the matrix $A + tI$ is positive-definite.  Thus, the matrix $(A+tI)B$ has non-negative eigenvalues.

Since the eigenvalues of a matrix depend continuously upon its entries, the eigenvalues of $\lim_{t \to 0^+} (A+tI)B = AB$ must be non-negative.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I couldn't understand the very last step of the proof: why $A^{\frac12} B A^{\frac12}$ is positive semi-definite?

Comment: Note that for any $x$, $x^*(C^*BC)x = (Cx)^*B(Cx) \geq 0$.

Comment: Sorry; I had a few "typos" there.  I meant to say that $C^*BC$ is [conrguent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_congruence) to a PSD matrix.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom "Since AB is similar to a positive semidefinite matrix, its eigenvalues are non-negative." This isnt clear to me at all

Comment: @Permian What part is unclear? Do you see that $A^{1/2}BA^{1/2}$ is positive semidefinite? Do you understand that positive semidefinite matrices have non-negative eigenvalues?