# Product of two symmetric matrices is similar to a symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices

> Let $A,B$ be symmetric real matrices. Is $AB$ similar to a symmetric matrix?

This is a problem in my exam. Not a conjecture :v

Comment: Oh sorry, it's actually in my exam

Comment: In fact AB is symmetric only if A and B commute.

Comment: Yeah. The difficulty here is that they do not

Comment: @Rohan as said for example in item 5 of (https://math.vanderbilt.edu/sapirmv/msapir/jan22.html).

Comment: @Rohan ... but the question of the OP is "is AB **similar** to a symmetric matrix...

Comment: Can people show me a solution and then downvote me later ?

Comment: @chítrungchâu What have you tried?

Comment: Somewhat related (http://mathoverflow.net/q/106191)(http://math.stackexchange.com/q/982797).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a counter-example of two symmetric matrices $A$, $B$ whose product, besides being non symmetrical, cannot be similar to a symmetric matrix.

Consider matrices

$$A=\pmatrix{1&2\\2&1} \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ B=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&-1}.$$

$AB=\pmatrix{1&-2\\2&-1}.$ which is non symmetric.

Moreover, the characteristic polynomial of $AB$ is $\lambda^2+3$: thus, the eigenvalues of $AB$ are $\pm i \sqrt{3}$. If it was similar to a symmetric matrix, it would have the same **real** eigenvalues.