# Is the product of two invertible symmetric matrices always diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

I have two symmetric matrices $A$ and $B$, which are both invertible. Their eigenvalues are obviously real, but not necessarily positive. I know that if one matrix were positive definite, we could use ([Product of two symmetric matrices is similar to a symmetric matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2053883/product-of-two-symmetric-matrices-is-similar-to-a-symmetric-matrix)) to show that $AB$ is similar to a symmetric matrix (with real eigenvalues). In my cases, the eigenvalues of $AB$ are generally complex, but can one adjust the proof to show that $AB$ is always diagonalizable?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No. Here is a counterexample that works not only over $\mathbb R$ but also over any field:
$$
\pmatrix{1&1\\ 0&1}=\pmatrix{1&1\\ 1&0}\pmatrix{0&1\\ 1&0}.
$$
In fact, it is known that *every* square matrix in a field $F$ is the product of two symmetric matrices over $F$. See Olga Taussky, [*The Role of Symmetric Matrices in the Study of General Matrices*](https://doi.org/10.1016/0024-3795(72)90024-9), Linear Algebra and Its Applications, 5:147-154, 1972 and also [*Positive-Definite Matrices and Their Role in the Study of the Characteristic Roots of General Matrices*](https://doi.org/10.1016/0001-8708(68)90020-0), Advances in Mathematics, 2(2):175-186, 1968.

Comment: I'm glad to see that the OP decided at last to mark your answer as the accepted one, since it is mucher better than mine.

Answer (score 7):

In general, no. Take$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 & \frac{15}{64}\end{bmatrix}\quad\text{and}\quad B=\begin{bmatrix}1&-4\\-4&0\end{bmatrix}.$$Then both $A$ and $B$ are symmetric and invertible. But$$AB=\begin{bmatrix}-3&-4\\\frac1{16}&-4\end{bmatrix},$$which is not diagonalizable: its only eigenvalue is $-\frac72$, and the corresponding eigenspace is $1$-dimensional.